# Selecting from another select statements results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL statements. I need one to select its results based on the selection from the other. The tables are not related. The only relation will be the results from the initial selection.

Initial selection...

```
SELECT 
    relatedseries 
FROM RelatedItems 
WHERE series = @getseries 
ORDER BY ID
```

Selection based on results of above selection...

```
SELECT 
    picid, 
    description 
FROM product_series 
WHERE newseries = relatedseries
```

I know this is incorrect, partly because I have tried it, but mostly I am sure the syntax is incorrect. But for example....

```
SELECT 
    picid, 
    description 
FROM product_series 
WHERE newseries = (
    SELECT 
        relatedseries 
    FROM RelatedItems 
    WHERE series = @getseries ORDER BY ID
)
```

How can I rewrite this to work and still achieve the results I require?

Comment: `IN` rather than `=` if you're just selecting by a single column. And ditch the `ORDER BY ID` because it's meaningless if you're just selecting `relatedseries`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` rather than 2 queries.

```
SELECT p.picid, p.description, r.relatedseries 
FROM product_series p
INNER JOIN RelatedItems r ON p.newseries = r.relatedseries
    AND r.series = @getseries
```

Get the data that you need in as few passes as you can manage.

NOTE: This may give you duplicates of p.picid and p.description if you have multiple records in RelatedItems that match up to product_series.

Comment: SQL is meant to be set-based, rather than procedural. It's a bit of a mindset shift, but as a developer, one of the best things you can do to keep your DBAs happy is to learn about the different types of `JOIN`s. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is my accepted answer, and it works great!! However, is there a way to order the results?

Comment: @cjtampa Which column do you need them ordered by? You can just add `ORDER BY <columnName>` to sort it how you need it.

Comment: `SELECT......ORDER BY r.id` would be similar to what you indicated above. That would give you your product_series columns ordered by the id of the row they JOIN to in RelatedItems.

Answer (score 0):

All's good aside for two issues, though the error message(s) should have been simple to understand.

1. You cannot have an `ORDER BY` clause in the nested `SELECT` statement. Try removing that piece.
2. Additionally, if your nested query is returning more than 1 result, you cannot have an equals before that query - replace that with IN.

> Corrected query

```
SELECT 
    picid, 
    description 
FROM product_series 
WHERE newseries IN (
    SELECT 
        relatedseries 
    FROM RelatedItems 
    WHERE series = @getseries 
    --ORDER BY ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN for multiple results from your first query

```
SELECT picid, 
       description 
  FROM product_series
 WHERE newseries IN (SELECT relatedseries 
                       FROM RelatedItems 
                      WHERE series = @getseries
                    )
 ORDER BY picid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with exists

```
SELECT picid, description FROM product_series WHERE newseries = relatedseries
Where 
exists (SELECT 1FROM RelatedItems WHERE series = @getseries ORDER BY ID)
```

Comment: You said ''The tables are not related ''

Comment: `WHERE newseries = relatedseries` indicates that the tables may not have an explicit relationship, but there is a relationship of two columns in the tables.

Comment: @Shawn Yes Got It ☺ thnx Man ☺

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use join

```
SELECT picid, description
FROM product_series
INNER JOIN RelatedItems ON newseries = relatedseries;
```

here is an example [sql join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NS.picid, NS.description 
FROM product_series NS, 
(SELECT relatedseries FROM RelatedItems WHERE
series = @getseries) RI
WHERE NS.newseries = RI.relatedseries
ORDER BY NS.picid ASC
```